# css min-width and margin/padding with absolute positioning

Tags: html, css

I'm using absolute positioning to have `100% height` of the screen. I also want to limit the `resizing` of my page so I add `min-width` in my header and content divs. The problem I'm facing is that once resizing reaches the min-width boundary, right side `margin disappears`. Any suggestions how to make it work?

HTML:

```
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="content">Content</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body{
    background: blue;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;

}

#header{
    height:30px;
    background: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    top:20px;
    right:20px;
    left:20px;
    min-width:500px;
}

#content{
    background:green;
     position: absolute;
    top:50px;
    right:20px;
    left:20px;
    bottom:20px;
    min-width:500px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A28St/)

Comment: your margin is not disappearing, it's being covered up by dragging the edge of the window over it...

Comment: I don't get what you mean by 'window over it'. I see that on the left side I have a 'gap' between window border and content and if I scroll to the right there is no gap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution my self. The problem is that if you apply `min-width` on the element which has `padding` or `margin`, that padding or margin collapses when you resize the window. So the solution was to wrap that element inside root element and **set min-width on the root element.**

P.S. I also tried box-sizing approach suggested by Sam but effect was almost the same: margin shrinks but doesn't disappear all. Applying min-width on outer element solves the issue as well.

Here is an example

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A28St/5/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [CSS box-sizing property](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) to accomplish this in modern browsers (IE8+)

Comment: How should I use it if I need a header as well?  I know I can use 'negative margins - padding' combination to offset header height but is it a preferable approach? And could you show an example of how to do it?